# How to check if thread made by module thread (in Python 3 _thread) is running?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Yet the thread module works for me. How to check if thread made by module thread (in Python 3 _thread) is running? When the function the thread is doing ends, the thread ends too, or doesn't?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.thread =None
......
if self.thread==None or not self.thread.isAlive() :
        self.thread = thread.start_new_thread(self.dosomething,())
else:
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("XXXX","There's no need to have more than two threads")
```

I know there is no function called isAlive() in "thread" module, is there any alternative?

But there isn't any reason why to use "threading" module, is there?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Perhaps you should give a short example of some code for which you are unclear about the behavior? And what do you mean `isn't any reason` to use threading- what if you want to add additional threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really need the low-level capabilities of the internal [`thread`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#module-thread) ([`_thread`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#module-_thread) module, you really should use the `threading` module instead. It makes everything easier to use and does come with helpers such as [`is_alive`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive).

Btw. the alternative of restarting a thread like you do in your example code would be to keep it running but have it wait for additional jobs. E.g. you could have a queue somewhere which keeps track of all jobs you want the thread to do, and the thread keeps working on them until the queue is empty—and then it will not terminate but wait for new jobs to appear. And only at the end of the application, you signalize the thread to stop waiting and terminate it.